# How to find a value from vector that match a condition?

Tags: r

for this data:

```
bn=seq(0.5,0.99,0.01)
nn=sqrt(30)*(0.3/sqrt(1-0.3^2))
bb=qt(x+(1-x)/2,30)
```

I want to find the first value (x)that will meet abs(nn)>bb from the values of bn starting from 0.99?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reverse bn, evaluate all options, and find min (first) match

```
> bn=rev(bn)
> bb=qt(bn+(1-bn)/2,30)
> bn[which.min(!(abs(nn)>bb))]
[1] 0.9
```

another option for finding the first match

```
> head(bn[abs(nn)>bb],1)
```

Comment: `options(digits=20)`, but all it will show you is floating-point error in this case ... or look at the help file for `format` ...